# Angular Universal: Exclude request from server

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm playing with Angular Universal for a while now and I'd like to exclude a request from being rendered on the server. Using TransferHttpCacheModule every `get` request will be rendered on the server, but sometimes it's useful that specific requests keep being asynchronous - imagine that a page makes many async requests and we just want to make one of them on the server for SEO purposes, I don't want to the others requests to being made on the server.

I've followed the docs until now: https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md.

Is there something we can do or the way I'm thinking is wrong and there's no problem all of these requests being rendered on the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it's isPlatformBrowser and then do the request.

```js
if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){
//the request
}
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know about that, and works like a charm. Thanks!